# How to sort RealmList objects using nested properties?

Tags: android, sorting, realm

I've started to work with Realm and I'm curious if it's possible to sort RealmList object by nested properties.

I have some ListModel object:

```
public class ListModel extends RealmObject {

   @Required
   private String itemName;
   ...
   private RealmList<ItemModel> items;
   ...
}
```

ItemModel is:

```
public class ItemModel extends RealmObject {

   private TagModel tag;
   ...
   private boolean isBought = false;

   @PrimaryKey
   private long created;
   ...
}
```

TagModel is:

```
public class TagModel extends RealmObject {

   @PrimaryKey
   private String tagName;
   ...
   private CategoryModel category;
   ...
}
```

and CategoryModel is:

```
public class CategoryModel extends RealmObject {

   @PrimaryKey
   private int categoryType;
   ...
}
```

So, what I really need is to have something like this:

```
RealmResults<ItemModel> sortedItems= realm.where(ListModel.class)
            .equalTo("created", created)
            .findFirst().getItems().where().findAllSorted("isBought", Sort.ASCENDING, "tag.category.categoryType", Sort.ASCENDING, "tag.tagName", Sort.ASCENDING);
```

Is it possible to achieve this somehow? For this moment, as I understand, it's impossible to use following structure `"tag.category.categoryType"` for my needs.

As a temporary solution I'm thinking about the following approach:

```
ListModel listModel = realm.where(ListModel.class)
      .equalTo("created", created)
      .findFirst();

List<ItemModel> items = listModel.getItems();
Collections.sort(items, new Comparator<ItemModel>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(ItemModel lhs, ItemModel rhs) {
            // here some sorting logic
      }
});
```

But i'm not sure this is a correct way.

Comment: Sorry, Realm doesn't support sorting by child's property right now :( See https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/709 . The side effect of you temp solution is the sorting needs to run in Realm transaction and the actual `RealmList` `items` in Realm will be changed after sorting. Maybe you want to create a new collection and sort that on instead.

Answer (score 1):

Gonzalo's approach looks good for now. But it was kind of slow because accessing nested items causes I/O.
In my case, It takes about 30 seconds with 10000 items.
So I refined it to use cache.

```
Collections.sort(medicineClassList, new Comparator<MedicineClass>() {
    Map<String, String> primaryKey2SortKey = new HashMap();
    @Override
    public int compare(MedicineClass lmo, MedicineClass rmo) {
        String lmo_string = pullSortKey(lmo);
        String rmo_string = pullSortKey(rmo);
        return lmo_string.compareToIgnoreCase(rmo_string);
    }

    private String pullSortKey(MedicineClass item) {
        if (primaryKey2SortKey.containsKey(item.getPrimaryKey())) {
            return primaryKey2SortKey.get(item.getPrimaryKey());
        }
        String sortKey = item.getProduct_request().getProduct().getName();
        primaryKey2SortKey.put(item.getPrimaryKey(), sortKey);
        return sortKey;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and i solved this with the same way, using Collections on RealmList

My sort need to order alphabetically the names of a List that are on the RealmList nested in main object

```
//medicineClassList is a RealmList with some RealmObjects

Collections.sort(medicineClassList, new Comparator<MedicineClass>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(MedicineClass lmo, MedicineClass rmo) {
        String lmo_string = lmo.getProduct_request().getProduct().getName();
        String rmo_string = rmo.getProduct_request().getProduct().getName();

        return lmo_string.compareToIgnoreCase(rmo_string);
    }
});
```

So then i use `medicineClassList` in a custom adapter to set the ListView where i put the results

Hope this helps.